# Get sibling attribute value depending on attribute of a preceding node

Tags: xml, vb.net, xpath

I have the following XML file and need to get the value of 3ed NODE element attribute VALUE (which is "offermann.com.au" and "cosmicpanda.biz" in our xml example) if the 1st NODE element attribute Value is D920.

```
<PRODUCT NAME="home" VERSION="9.0.408" MAJOR="90000" MINOR="198">
    <ITEM NAME="plugins">
        <ITEM NAME="ADDRLISTS" VERSION="1">
            <ITEM NAME="USER">
                <ITEM NAME="BL" DELETE="1">
                    <ITEM NAME="1">
                        <NODE NAME="F" TYPE="number" VALUE="D920" />
                        <NODE NAME="A" TYPE="string" VALUE="@offermann.com.au" />
                        <NODE NAME="N" TYPE="string" VALUE="offermann.com.au" />
                    </ITEM>
                    <ITEM NAME="2">
                        <NODE NAME="F" TYPE="number" VALUE="D920" />
                        <NODE NAME="A" TYPE="string" VALUE="@cosmicpanda.biz" />
                        <NODE NAME="N" TYPE="string" VALUE="cosmicpanda.biz" />
                    </ITEM>
                </ITEM>
            </ITEM>
        </ITEM>
    </ITEM>
</PRODUCT>
```

In VB .Net, I can get all Nodes that the attribute NAM = N as follows

```
Dim nodeList As XmlNodeList = root.SelectNodes("//NODE[@NAME='N']")
```

but this brings all nodes that I don't need.
How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this XPath-1.0 expression:

```
//ITEM[@NAME='BL']/ITEM[NODE[@NAME='F' and @VALUE='D920']]/NODE[@NAME='N']/@VALUE
```

Or, to get the respective element nodes in VB.Net:

```
Dim AttValue As String

For Each Element As XmlElement In XmlDoc.SelectNodes("//ITEM[@NAME='BL']/ITEM[NODE[@NAME='F' and @VALUE='D920']]/NODE[@NAME='N']")    
  AttValue = Element.Attributes.ItemOf("VALUE").InnerText;
  Console.WriteLine("The value is: " + AttValue)
Next
```

Be aware that this sample code does not include error checking (For example, the `@VALUE` attribute not being present).

Comment: Thanks, the 2nd statement worksbut gets all nodes that have a value  of "D920". In fact, I reduced the xml lines for the sake of the thread, I will give a full example of the xml content hereafter

Comment: With the second statement you will get all **elements** that have an attribute `NAME` with the value `N`. Then you will have to retrieve the attribute value of `VALUE` from each `nodeList` item with a separate statement.

Comment: How? I am not able to figure it out

Comment: xz, this will give the value of offermann.com.au related to N which I already do. I need to check the node before its value is D920 then get the vallue of the Node which its name is N

Comment: I added another approach to my answer. I hope that all misunderstandings are resolved now.

Comment: You are the right GUY, so many thanks I am getting the expected results like a charm, so many thanks again

Comment: Thank you. I would appreciate if you would also show your appreciation by clicking on the arrow left to the answer. Glad I could help.

Comment: I did sir, but still I see 0 after clicking the arrow

Comment: I do not see this answer as being accepted. Because you seem to be new to SO, take the (2min of) time to take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). It's worth it and will improve your overall experience with SO in the long run.